# Iterating over nested list and count specific value

Tags: python

I have this nested list:

```
d = ['good morning', 'hello', 'chair', 'python', ['music', 'flowers', 
    'facebook', 'instagram', 'snapchat', ['On my Own', 'monster', 'Words 
     dont come so easily', 'lead me right']], 'Stressed Out', 'Pauver 
     Coeur', 'Reach for Tomorrow', 'mariners song', 'Wonder sleeps here']
```

I need to iterate through the list so that if the character ‘m’ is in the string, then it should be added to a new list called `m_list`.

What I tried so far is the following:

```
m_list = []
for el in d:
    print(" Level1: {}".format(el))
    if type(el) is str:
        if 'm' in el:
            m_list.append(el)
    for el2 in el:
        print(" Level2: {}".format(el2))
        if type(el2) is str:
            if 'm' in el2:
                m_list.append(el2)
        for word in el2:
            print(" Level3: {}".format(word))
            if type(word) is str:
                if 'm' in word:
                   m_list.append(word)
```

I know that I do not set up correctly the code because inner loop will double count some elements. 
As example here:

```
print(m_list)

['good morning', 'm', 'm', 'music', 'm', 'instagram', 'm', 'On my Own', 
'monster', 'Words dont come so easily', 'lead me right', 'Reach for 
Tomorrow', 'm', 'm', 'mariners song', 'm', 'm']
```

I solved this using this inefficient code:

```
s = set(m_list)
m_list = list(s)
m_list.remove('m')
print(m_list) 
['monster', 'mariners song', 'Words dont come so easily', 'Reach for 
Tomorrow', 'On my Own', 'lead me right', 'music', 'good morning', 
'instagram']
```

My question how I can change for loop in order to work correctly to count character **'m'** and assign to **m_list**?

P.S. I am not proficient user of Python. I would like to improve my skills. Would you like to suggest me smarter way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not sure of the depth of your nesting then you need a recursive approach like this:

```
def find_char(char, words):
        result = []
        for word in words:
          if isinstance(word,list):
            result += find_char(char,word)
          else:
            if char in word:
              result.append(word)
        return result

>>> d = ['good morning', 'hello', 'chair', 'python', ['music', 'flowers',
'facebook', 'instagram', 'snapchat', ['On my Own', ['monster'], 'Words don`t come so easily', 'lead me right']], 'Stressed Out', 'Pauver Coeur', 'Reach for Tomorrow', 'mariners song', 'Wonder sleeps here']

>>> find_char("m",d)
['good morning', 'music', 'instagram', 'On my Own', 'monster', 'Words don`t come so easily', 'lead me right', 'Reach for Tomorrow', 'mariners song']
```

This will work no matter how deeply your list is nested.

Comment: Super elegant way to solve it. One question what does isinstance function doing?

Comment: The code needs to know if the next thing it is looking at (in `word`) is a string or a list. `isinstance(myvar,mytype)` is another way to write `type(myvar) is mytype` but has the advantage that it knows about subclasses, and so some regard it as better style.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a generic custom function that calls itself if you have list within or appends the value to new list if it contains `'m'` in it:

```
d = ['good morning', 'hello', 'chair', 'python', ['music', 'flowers', 
    'facebook', 'instagram', 'snapchat', ['On my Own', 'monster', 'Words  dont come so easily', 'lead me right']], 'Stressed Out', 'Pauver Coeur', 'Reach for Tomorrow', 'mariners song', 'Wonder sleeps here']

def find_all_values(d, m, m_list=[]):
    for x in d:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            find_all_values(x, m, m_list)
        elif m in x:
            m_list.append(x) 
    return m_list


m_list = find_all_values(d, 'm')
# ['good morning', 'music', 'instagram', 'On my Own', 'monster', 'Words  dont come so easily', 'lead me right', 'Reach for Tomorrow', 'mariners song']

m_list_count = len(m_list)
# 9
```

Now that you have a generic custom function, you can use this to create list that holds values containing *any letter* and get its count.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive solution

```
data = ['good morning', 'hello', 'chair', 'python', ['music', 'flowers', 'facebook', 'instagram', 'snapchat',
                                                 ['On my Own', 'monster', 'Words dont come so easily',
                                                  'lead me right']], 'Stressed Out', 'Pauver Coeur',
    'Reach for Tomorrow', 'mariners song', 'Wonder sleeps here']

m_holder = []


def m_finder(lst, m_holder):
    for word_or_list in lst:
        if isinstance(word_or_list, str):
            if 'm' in word_or_list:
                m_holder.append(word_or_list)
        else:
            m_finder(word_or_list, m_holder)


m_finder(data, m_holder)
print(m_holder)
```

Output:

```
['good morning', 'music', 'instagram', 'On my Own', 'monster', 'Words dont come so easily', 'lead me right', 'Reach for Tomorrow', 'mariners song']
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3:

```
def myflatten(l):
    for elem in l:
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            yield from myflatten(elem)
        else:
            if 'm' in elem:
                yield elem

list(myflatten(d))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
d = ['good morning', 'hello', 'chair', 'python', ['music', 'flowers', 'facebook', 'instagram', 'snapchat', ['On my Own', 'monster', 'Words dont come so easily', 'lead me right']], 'Stressed Out', 'Pauver Coeur', 'Reach for Tomorrow', 'mariners song', 'Wonder sleeps here']

m_list = []
for i in d:
    if type(i) is list:
        for inner_l in i:
            if type(inner_l) is list:
                for in_l2 in inner_l:
                    if 'm' in in_l2:
                        m_list.append(in_l2)
            elif 'm' in inner_l:
                m_list.append(inner_l)
    elif 'm' in i:
        m_list.append(i)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the inner `for` loop not to run if the element is a string. There are two common ways that apply to your case:

1. Add an `else` clause to the preceding `if` and indent the `for` loop. This translates into "run this code *only* if the element isn't a string":

   ```
   if type(el) is str:
       if 'm' in el:
           m_list.append(el)
   else:
       for el2 in el:
           ...
   ```
2. Add a `continue` statement if the element is a string. This translates to "don't do anything else if you have a string":

   ```
   if type(el) is str:
       if 'm' in el:
           m_list.append(el)
       continue
   for el2 in el:
   ```

Personally I like the first version because it is more explicit. At the same time, the second version saves you a level of indentation in the rest of your code, which can be very nice as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate continue solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m_list = []
for el in d:   
    if type(el) is str:
        if 'm' in el:
            m_list.append(el)
    else:
        for el2 in el:   
            if type(el2) is str:
                if 'm' in el2:
                    m_list.append(el2)
            else:
                for word in el2:
                    if type(word) is str:
                        if 'm' in word:
                           m_list.append(word)

print(m_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple solution to your answer try this:

```
    d = ['good morning', 'hello', 'chair', 'python', ['music', 'flowers', 
    'facebook', 'instagram', 'snapchat', ['On my Own', 'monster',
'Words dont come so easily', 'lead me right']], 'Stressed Out', 'Pauver Coeur', 
    'Reach for Tomorrow', 'mariners song', 'Wonder sleeps here']


m_list=[]

for v in d:
    if 'm' in v:
        m_list.append(v)
    if type(v) is list:
        for x in v:
            if 'm' in x:
                m_list.append(x)
            if type(x)is list:
                for y in x:
                    if 'm' in y:
                        m_list.append(y)
                    if type(y) is list:
                        for f in z:
                            if 'm' in f:
                                m_list.append(f)
                        
                       
print(m_list)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).